# Desktop files with superuser privileges

Tags: sudo, .desktop, matlab, gksudo

I have Matlab installed under `/home/fer/Matlab`, with the main exec file being `/home/fer/Matlab/R2014b/bin/matlab`. There is something weird with it and it only works if I open it with the terminal using `sudo`. If I run it without sudo it throws a permission error and closes (I guess it's reading somewhere).

Anyway, I was trying to create a `.desktop` file to be able to open it from the menu, and because it needs to run under sudo, in the exec line I wrote:

```
Exec=gksudo -u root /home/fer/Matlab/R2014b/bin/matlab
```

When I click on the shortcut, it asks me for my password, then the Matlab splash appears, then closes, and nothing happens. This looks a lot like a problem with Matlab itself, but am I doing it right with the exec line of the .desktop file? Do I need to add anything else? If a program requires a terminal to run from, is there anyway I can emulate one from the desktop file?

EDIT: As asked in comments:
whoami outputs `fer` and all files and subdirectories in Matlab/R2014b are owned by user `fer` and group `fer`. The error is written in a Matlab window, saying tht there is not write permission on /home/fer/.matlab/R2014b/temp0x... I will try to look into that directory.

Comment: You should not have to start Matlab as root. What error messages are issued when you start it as a normal user **and** Please post the output of this command in your question: `ls -la /home/user/Matlab`

Comment: Not directly to your question, but you may omit the`-u root` argument of `gksudo`, as it runs the following executable as root by default, if no user is specified.

Comment: When you run Matlab in the terminal without `sudo`, do you get any error messages like "permission denied on /path/to/file"? That would be helpful to see what it wants to access and changing your user account's permissions to be able to access this file or directory.

Comment: Please post the output of this command in your question: `whoami` and `groups`.

Comment: Can you put the executable in / ?

Comment: @ByteCommander Edited with that information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<sub>Cut out and reworded from @MyUserIsThis' edits to his question:</sub>

Ok, I `chown`ed recursively the whole directory `/home/<user>/.matlab` so I would have permissions to write on it and it was fixed.

BTW, in case someone else runs into this, the exec line of the desktop file should include the option `-desktop` for the script to work properly when not called from the terminal:

```
Exec=/home/<user>/Matlab/R2014b/bin/matlab -desktop
```

Comment: @MyUserIsThis Please accept this answer, because AskUbuntu is a Q&A site which implies that if a question is solved, it should have an accepted answer. If you want to add something, feel free to edit it - it's a community wiki which means every user my contribute to it.